# Issue on parsing fisheye log with sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm parsing logs and based on error i want to find the the list repositories which cause the following error the last 7 days:

```
2016-09-21 14:57:11,234 WARN  - Exception during FishEye Incremental Indexing of TEST-REPO1: com.cenqua.fisheye.config.ConfigException: com.atlassian.fisheye.dvcs.handler.DvcsProcessException: Error while communicating with VCS: GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.

2016-09-21 15:07:23,379 WARN  - Exception during FishEye Incremental Indexing of TEST-REPO2: com.cenqua.fisheye.config.ConfigException: com.atlassian.fisheye.dvcs.handler.DvcsProcessException: Error while communicating with VCS: GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
```

To get it i'm using sed:

```
sed -n "/$last_day/,/$current_date/p" /home/atlassian/crucible.data/var/log/fisheye.out | grep -i "project you were looking" | awk '{ print $11 }' | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

but I'm getting:

```
TEST-REPO1:
TEST-REPO2:
you
found.
```

As result i want:

```
TEST-REPO1
TEST-REPO2
```

Comment: The input file you showed is exactly this? Your result looks like you have other stuff after those lines. Also I don’t get why you use `| awk '!x[$0]++'` at the end. As for `sed`, if you want to display everything from a certain date, you can use `sed -n "/$last_day/,$p"` (i.e. you don’t need `$current_date`).

Comment: @vdavid yes, the input file exactly this, if use sed -n "/$last_day/,$p" I got error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unexpected `,'

Comment: My bad, I should have escaped the $ sign: `sed -n "/$last_day/,\$p"`. I’m glad you have found an answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'[: ]' -v l="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d' 7 days ago')" '
 /project you were looking/ && $1>=l && !seen[$14]++{
   print $14
}' log
```

Your current log input file is `21-09-2016` is `159` days old as on today `27-02-2017` so with above command you get nothing as output to check whether command is working or not you may try below

```
awk -F'[: ]' -v l="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d' 159 days ago')" '
     /project you were looking/ && $1>=l && !seen[$14]++{
       print $14
    }' log
```

Comment: that is exactly that i want! Thanks!